# exc_bad_access caused by sprintf

Tags: c++, c, exc-bad-access, fread, fseek

I'm getting an error exc_bad_access in xcode when executing the following code.

The error is caused by the following line:

```
//Add new line at beginning of hex decode
p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\n");
```

Could this be because when the pointer *p is created it isn't pointing to a memory address? If so, any idea how to point it to a memory address?

```
const char *current = "myfile";
FILE *f = fopen(current, "rb");
if (!f)
{
printf(  "Unable to open file! %s", current);
    return;
}
char ch;
int loop = 1;
int sz1,sz2,sz3;

int seeker = offsetof(struct myStruct, contents.datas);

struct myStruct c;

fseek(f,16,SEEK_SET);

//Find specific ID part of struct for printing later
size_t n = fread(&c.ID, sizeof(int), 1, f);

if (n != 1) {
    printf(  "Error Reading File" );
    return;
} else {
    printf("Success reading ID" );
}

int val;
val=fseek(f,0L,SEEK_SET);

if(val!=0)
{
    post( "problem fseeking" );
    return;
}

//find total length of file
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
sz1 = ftell(f);

//total length minus length from position which seeker is set
fseek(f, seeker, SEEK_SET);
sz2 = sz1 - ftell(f) + 1;

//Determine count for 80 chars and 7 tabs per new line 
int tabs = (sz2 / 80) * 16;// Total size / size of chunk * 8 - 7 tabs and 1 new line char
sz3 = ((sz2 * 2) + tabs + 1 + 16) ;//Total size + nuls + tabs * 2 for 2 bytes

//Create buffer the correct size
char buffer[sz3];
buffer[0] = '\0';

//Create pointer variable to copy to buffer
char *p = buffer;

//Add new line at beginning of hex decode
p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\n");

while (loop < sz2)
{
    if(loop % 40 -
        //Add 7 tabs to the beginning of each new line 1 == 4 ){
        p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
    }
    //Error happening here
    size_t nn = fread(&ch, 1, 1, f);
    if (nn != 1) {
        printf("Errorno: %s", strerror(errno) );
        return;
    } else {
        //printf("Sucess");
    }

    fread(&ch, 1, 1, f);
    if(loop > 4){
        //Convert char to hex
        p += sprintf(p, "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));
    }

    if(loop % 40 == 4){
        if(loop > 4){
            //Add a new line every 80 chars
            p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\n");
        }
    }
    loop++;
}
```

Comment: _Could this be because when the pointer *p is created it isn't pointing to a memory address?_........ but your code init it to buffer address, so it is pointing to something valid as far as buffer size can is enough

Comment: Any idea of an example of how to point to a memory address? Sorry, I'm quite new to this and am stuck on how to do this...

Comment: `const char *current = 'myfile';` is a syntax error, should be `const char *current = "myfile";`

Comment: Weather Vane, how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: Because if you are executing compiled code, this is not the code that you compiled. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Weather Vane, I've just used this filename as an example, its not in the final code.

Comment: sorry, dhke, I do not understand a word you are saying...

Comment: Then this is a perfect example of why the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is requested. Is there anything else that only resembles the actual code?

Comment: @Ke. The code in your question is supposed to be a minimally, working example that demonstrates your problem. If you change your code to something that doesn't compile, you are making life harder for those that want to help you. That said, we are also debugging different code than the one you are running, which kind of moot, isn't it?

Comment: Weather Vane, it is impossible for me to supply the exact code, because it is c/c++ embedded within another program. It is not running inside the OS, and is an adapted framework for building c/c++ programs. This should not deter from the fact that the code would still have the error, irrespective of this discussion. Clearly it's an issue with a pointer. Do you have any examples how to tackle this problem, or are you just here to critique other peoples code?

Comment: dhke, not it isnt moot, I've tested this code and it still has the same problem...

Comment: @Ke. `//Create buffer the correct size` -- You are doing a high-wire act here.  If you're off by a single byte, you are invoking undefined behavior.  .  Second, you tagged this as C++, but this `char buffer[sz3];` is not valid C++, as arrays cannot be declared using a variable as the number of entries.

Comment: "I've tested this code" - wouldn't it be great if *we could do the same*.   I highly suspect your math in computing the size of the buffer (`sz3`) in comparison to how much data you're actually *writing* is not correct. or perhaps an automatic var overflow. Given, I can't verify that, but *you apparently can*, and should via your stated capability to "test" this.

Comment: Hi PaulMcKenzie, yes I can mix c and c++ in this program at the same time. I'm guessing this is going to be much easier if i just rewrite the whole thing in c++.

Comment: @Ke. -- As stated, that computation of the exact buffer size is a recipe for disaster.  I've seen it fail more times than work, and the many times it did fail were only detected *after* months (sometimes years) of the program "running ok" with the hidden bug.

Comment: Hi Paul Mackenzie, would you suggest for me to rewrite it as c++, will it be easier to compute the buffer size, or not necessary? I say this because I've already tried to write this program in c++ and it seemed to me more difficult.

Comment: What is the value of `sz3`? Your array is allocated on the stack and the stack is of limited size on OS X.

Comment: Hi Hristo Lliev, it is variable (the size of the file), I'm wondering how I could put this on the heap - sorry Im a bit of a newb...

Comment: This is not a solution, but just try to replace `char buffer[sz3];` by `char buffer[sz * 2];` and look if the problem goes away. If yes, it is a strong indication that something is seriously wrong with the calculation of the buffer length.

Comment: Put it into heap using [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html): `char *p = malloc(sz3); if (p != NULL){...} free(p);`

Comment: Hi LPs, I get a "cannot initialize a variable of type char * with an rvalue of type void *

Comment: Are you compiling with c++? Btw remember to use @ char before the nick to warn a user.

Answer (score 1):

First of all *p is pointing to valid memory in your program because of line
char *p = buffer;

But I think the problem is in buffer size, please make sure that buffer size is enough to hold the strings which you are putting in.
I am sure that statement "p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
" is the cause of problem and it may be due to the insufficient size of buffer array which is pointed by pointer p.

Comment: Hi user3059968, yes agree, but it's happening above in the first sprintf statement... agreed it must have to do with my byte calculations...

Comment: @Ke Can you please tell me what are the value of tabs, sz2 and sz3.

Comment: So the program basically chops up the string of bytes into 80 character chunks (hence the /80) and then adds 1 new line to the beginning, 1 new line to the end, and 7 tabs + 1 newline on each line in between.

Comment: That's fine but can you print the values of tabs,sz2 and sz3, from those values we will get the better idea.

Comment: Hi Vrana,  sz1: 516276 ,
 sz2: 516116 ,
sz3: 1083857 , tabs: 51608 many thanks for helping with this

Comment: Please make sure that the code which you shared and which you are running are same. In the above comment you told that value of sz1, sz2, sz3 and tabs are 516276, 516116, 1083857 and 51608 respectively.     But as per the statement "tabs = (sz2 / 80) *16" value of tabs should be 103216.  If tabs value is 103216 then sz3 will be 1135465 and your program will run fine. I checked it through a dummy program.